# elasticsearch 2.0 ttl in php

Tags: php, elasticsearch, ttl

In 1.X Elasticsearch we have had _ttl organized in following way: 
In the mapping we have had:

```
{
  "_ttl" : {
    "enabled" : true,
    "default" : "30d"
  },
  "_timestamp" : {
    "enabled" : true,
    "path" : "@ts",
    "format" : "dateOptionalTime"
  }
}
```

And it meant that given document should be expired after 30 days from the time described in `@ts` field. Currently in Elasticsearch 2.0 the `_timestamp` field can not have 'path' field and is deprecated so I can not use that method to tell Elasticsearch when to expire given document. 
So I can still use `_ttl` 30d in the index mapping but then the document will expire 30 days from the indexing and if I want to expire it 30 days from the time as in `@ts` field then I need to calculate relative time from indexing and add it as a get parameter of HTTP request:

```
PUT my_index/my_type/1?ttl=10m 
{
  "text": "Will expire in 10 minutes"
}
```

So my question is how do I express that in terms of PHP Elasticsearch driver ?

```
$params = [
  'index' => 'my_index',
  'type' => 'my_type',
  'id' => 'my_id',
  'body' => ['testField' => 'abc']
];
$response = $client->index($params);
```

Comment: Note that the `_ttl` field is also deprecated in ES 2.0. Why not simply using daily indices and using the [curator tool](https://github.com/elastic/curator) (or similar) you can easily remove all indices older than 30 days?

Comment: I  know that _ttl is deprecated, but it is unfortunate, If I have 10 different indexes let say for 10 different logs then I need to deal with 300 daily indexes it is messy and I would rather not do that.